# Teamviewer 11 won't work on Ubuntu 20 Login Screen

Tags: 20.04, teamviewer

I successfully installed Teamviewer 11 on Ubuntu 20 (I need it cause i have paid license TV11) using these commands:

1. wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_11x/teamviewer_i386.deb
2. sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
3. sudo apt install libc6:i386 libasound2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libsm6:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386 libsystemd0:i386
4. wget [http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/libpng12/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1~ppa0~eoan_i386.deb](http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/libpng12/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1%7Eppa0%7Eeoan_i386.deb)
5. sudo apt install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1~ppa0~eoan_i386.deb
6. sudo dpkg -i ./teamviewer_i386.deb
7. wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6_2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
8. ar -x ./libfreetype6_2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
9. tar -xvf ./data.tar.xz
10. sudo cp -r ./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/lib
11. sudo cp ./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.12.1 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/lib
12. reboot

After reboot and Log in to my account, everything works fine.
But, when I lock screen (not sleep) or restart without logging into my acc, i can't access via Teamviewer.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**

For me the issue was using Wayland.

Open Gnome DM config file

```
sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Disable Wayland on the login screen

```
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

**Another work around:**

I found I was able to ssh in and restart the teamviewer service, my teamveiwer login would then work.

```
teamviewer daemon restart
```

**Extra Info:**

There was a message I found that threw me off the trail, this message didn't go away when I did finally fix it.

```
May 30 21:23:02 hostname systemd[1]: Starting TeamViewer remote control daemon...
May 30 21:23:14 hostname systemd[1]: teamviewerd.service: Can't open PID file /run/teamviewerd.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
May 30 21:23:15 hostname systemd[1]: Started TeamViewer remote control daemon.
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on three machines with TeamViewer.  One has a Nvidia 3060, one has a Nvidia 710, one has a Nvidia 9300M. Only the 9300M has trouble.

I saw other posts talking about lightdm fixing their issue, but I have no confirmation on that.

See [their note](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/24537/update-teamviewer-13) about how they don't fully support wayland yet, in 2017, I am sure they aren't going to be working too hard at supporting hardware from 2008.